# Split strings and replace in a column of dataframe

Tags: python, string, dataframe, replace, split

I am trying to split strings of a dataframe column and then change some of these strings. The probleme I am getting is that the first string in the column is changed but other strings are deleted.

Here is a sample of the dataframe:

```
                         type           nature
0                 coca, pepsi  coca, champagne
1  budweiser, coca, champagne             coca
2                       pepsi       wine, coke
3                  coke, coca             bev.
4                        bev.             bev.
5                        bev.             bev.
6                        bev.             bev.
```

Here is my code :

```
df.type = df.type.str.split(",", n = 7, expand = True)
df.type = df.type.replace(to_replace=r'^co.*$', value='coca', regex=True)
print(df.type)

0         coca
1         coca
2    budweiser
3         coca
4        pepsi
5         wine
6         coca
Name: type, dtype: object
```

Actual results are :

```
0         coca
1         coca
2    budweiser
3         coca
4        pepsi
5         wine
6         coca
Name: type, dtype: object
```

While I would like to change also in the column 'budweiser' by 'beer', 'champagne' by 'fancy drink', etc... But they are deleted.
Also cherry on the cake : I would like to remove duplicates as in line 3.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: The question is quite unclear to me. Do you wish to replace, in the `df['type']` column, all the `budweiser` by `beer` and the `champagne` by `fancy drink` ?

Comment: IMCoins : yes that's exactly it but on row 1 for eg I want to keep also beer (replacing "budweiser) and coca. And when I get the same beverage twice in the column (for eg row 3 will become 'coca, coca') delete replicates. Hope it is clearer. Many thanks.